# Bootstrap transparent navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the navbar transparent kinda like [this](http://cleancanvas.herokuapp.com/).  But I can't seem to get it to work.  I've added `rga(0,0,0,0.5)` on the `navbar` class.

Comment: I think you got the syntax `rga(0,0,0,0.5)`? I believe it should be `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just figured it out. For anyone who needs this in the future. I added a `CSS` override that was:

```
.navbar.transparent.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

And my `html` syntax looks like:

```
<div class="navbar transparent navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <nav class="navbar-inner">
   ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can even use like this

```
.navbar-default {
  background: none;
}
```

or

```
.navbar {
  background: none;
}
```

You'll get transparent background.

Answer (score 7):

For a transparent navbar, it's pretty easy. In the CSS document you can do one of three things.

A. The easy way, but you don't learn too much with this method. You can literally type in the CSS document that the background of the navbar is transparent. Pretty simple:

```
.navbar
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

B. You can indirectly set the alpha channel for the RGBA background color to something in between 0 and 1. The R, G, and B coordinates control the red, green, and blue of the pixels, respectively. The A, or alpha channel, controls the opacity/transparency. For the R, G, and B, you can input a value in between 0 and 255. However, for the A alpha channel, you must input a value in between 0 and 1. 1 means it is completely opaque (not transparent, aka fully visible), and 0 means it is completely transparent (invisible). Setting different values for the alpha channel can help you decide how transparent you want your navbar to be. Very useful if you make the navbar a fixed-top one and you have different background colors throughout your webpage.

Oh, and speaking of colors...there's more.

You can take this a step further. If you want your navbar to be transparent and have a lighter/whitish tint, you can do the following.

```
.navbar
{
    /* White tint with 0.5 opacity. */
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    /* Notice how RGB of 255,255,255 is white. */
}
```

Or, if you want your navbar to be transparent with a darker, blacker tint, you can do the following:

```
.navbar
{
    /* Example with a black tint and 0.5 opacity. */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    /* RGB of 0,0,0 is black. */
}
```

Now, if you want to give your transparent navbar, for example, a green tint, mess around with the G green value! For red, mess around with the R value. For blue, mess around with the B value. For a hex green of #008f00, or (0,143,0) in RGB, it would be something like this:

```
.navbar
{
    /* Green tint of RGB 0,143,0, and with 0.5 opacity. */
    background-color: rgba(0,143,0,0.5);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how recent an addition this is, but in Bootstrap v4.5, you simply need to add the `bg-transparent` classname to your navbar's class attribute, like so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
```

Here's Bootstrap's documentation on color utility classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/colors/#background-color

Comment: this is the correct answer since he mentioned the bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

First I think you have the wrong syntax for RGB or RGBA you wrote

```
rga(0,0,0,0.5)
```

When in fact it should be

```
rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Let take this for an example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu1</li>
    <li>Menu2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .navbar {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
```

I would also suggest to have a fallback color, just in case the browser people be using doesn't support it.

**CSS Fallback**

```
   .navbar {
       background: rgb (0,0,0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap 5.1, you can try to add

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    var height = 200;

    if (top > height) {
        //sticky-top or fixed-top
        jQuery('.sticky-top').addClass('bg-opacity-75');
    } else {
        jQuery('.sticky-top').removeClass('bg-opacity-75');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you can't usually just style the .navbar if you have multiple of them for reasons that they make good button organizers and you can create a horizontal-to-vertical flipping navbar for mobile usage.

The following screenshot shows that if you delete "bg-dark" and do nothing else, then the navbar should show up transparent.

If it doesn't then use Chrome debug tools to find and inspect the colored element. That's where you'll probably want to add a id="my-element" to that html tag.  Then in the CSS file, style #my-element with background : transparent.

[image]

I could not for some reason add an id and style the id with bg-dark present.   So if you're having trouble, just remove bg-dark from the class list of the colored item.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"></nav>
```

when use `bg-light`
change style as following

```
.bg-light {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

Comment: and you broke `bg-light` all across your site

Answer (score 0):

Consider that your code is like this

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed="top">
</Navbar>
```

Just add the following code into your CSS that's it

```
.bg-dark {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 5, just delete '**bg**' property from your Navbar or set it to empty string:

```
<Navbar bg="">
```

As @PenAndPaperMathematics mentioned before by deleting 'bg-dark'